# Fetching html from a URL

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I'm trying to fetch the search results from a digital library by accessing the following URL:

http://search.lib.monash.edu/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?dscnt=0&frbg=&scp.scps=scope%3A%2861MONASH_AU%29%2Cscope%3A%28catcarm%29%2Cscope%3A%28arrow%29%2Cscope%3A%28arrow%29%2Cscope%3A%28MUA%29%2Cscope%3A%28catau%29%2Cprimo_central_multiple_fe&tab=default_tab&dstmp=1397132268717&srt=rank&ct=search&mode=Basic&dum=true&indx=1&vl%28freeText0%29=java&fn=search&vid=MON

This url works just fine from any web browser, however, when I try to read this URL from my java application it returns this html file, which seems that it redirects the application to another page:

```
<!-- filename: sso -->
<html>
<head> 
<title>Login </title> 
<!-- START filename: meta-tags.pds --> 
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<!-- END   filename: meta-tags.pds --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://monash-dc05.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com:8991/PDSMExlibris.css"   type="text/css" /> 
</head> 
<body onload="location = '/goto/http://search.lib.monash.edu:80/primo_library/libweb/action/login.do?afterPDS=true&amp;vid=MON&amp;vid=MON&amp;dscnt=0&amp;targetURL=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.lib.monash.edu%2Fprimo_library%2Flibweb%2Faction%2Fsearch.do%3Fdscnt%3D0&amp;frbg=&amp;tab=default%5Ftab&amp;dstmp=1397132076758&amp;srt=rank&amp;ct=search&amp;mode=Basic&amp;dum=true&amp;indx=1&amp;tb=&amp;vl%28freeText0%29=java&amp;fn=search&amp;pds_handle=GUEST';"> 
 <noscript> 
 <div id="header"> 
 <div> 
 <img src="http://monash-dc05.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com:8991//exlibris/primo/p4_1/pds/html_form/icon/exlibrislogo.jpg" alt="Exlibris Logo" />
 <p>&nbsp;</p> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
 <div id="connect"> 
 <a href="/goto/http://search.lib.monash.edu:80/primo_library/libweb/action/login.do?afterPDS=true&amp;vid=MON&amp;vid=MON&amp;dscnt=0&amp;targetURL=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.lib.monash.edu%2Fprimo_library%2Flibweb%2Faction%2Fsearch.do%3Fdscnt%3D0&amp;frbg=&amp;tab=default%5Ftab&amp;dstmp=1397132076758&amp;srt=rank&amp;ct=search&amp;mode=Basic&amp;dum=true&amp;indx=1&amp;tb=&amp;vl%28freeText0%29=java&amp;fn=search&amp;pds_handle=GUEST">Return from Check SSO </a> 
 </div>    
 </noscript>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I hardcoded the page to which my application is redirected and the code simple:

```
String url="http://search.lib.monash.edu:80/primo_library/libweb/action/login.do?afterPDS=true&amp;vid=MON&amp;vid=MON&amp;dscnt=0&amp;targetURL=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.lib.monash.edu%2Fprimo_library%2Flibweb%2Faction%2Fsearch.do%3Fdscnt%3D0&amp;frbg=&amp;tab=default%5Ftab&amp;dstmp=1397132076758&amp;srt=rank&amp;ct=search&amp;mode=Basic&amp;dum=true&amp;indx=1&amp;tb=&amp;vl%28freeText0%29=java&amp;fn=search&amp;pds_handle=GUEST";
Document d=Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(60000).get();
```

The page to which the application is redirected (as defined in body onload) is not available.

My question is how I can fetch the html file from the above URL using my java application the same way I'm getting it from my browser?

This digital library has no API or any exposed services otherwise I would use them.

Comment: read the title of the page returned: This is the logon page of the library. Your java objects calling http addresses need to supply credentials at least once.

Comment: @collapsar, yes it is log on page but why the page is available without credentials from the browser?

Comment: @Reimeus, I just added the code. It is simple and only connects to the redirected page.

Comment: most certainly it isn't. at least once you must have submitted login data to a library page. upon success, a browser will store these credentials and re-submit it automatically. in fact there are several more methods to accomplish it, e.g. cookies (little pieces of data supplied by a web application server and stored in your browser) or specially crafted links. some (poorly designed) pages analyse the (effectively putative) kind of your browser. any such scenario needs to be handled by you or the java classes you use.

Comment: @collapsar thanks for your answer. But I'm pretty sure it does not need any credentials. Try access that URL and you can see that the page is available.

Comment: i've compared my eventual url with the one you gave. there are 2 differences: 1.) there is an additional parameter `&fromLogin=true`that you should try to append to your url 2.) the different timestamp. maybe yours is too old, try `&dstmp=1397135722316`( instead of `&dstmp=1397132268717` )

Comment: @collapsar Same thing! the redirected page is not available. I get  http 404 code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you receive several cookies when logging in. among others, a session-id is allocated to you. you can have a look at the cookies by opening the developer tools in chrome ( ctrl+shift+j ), enter the console, reload/load the libraray page, and enter 'document.cookie' in the console. on my system i have `JSESSIONID=B644635A77414134F64C338764C215B4; sto-id-?PD_PROD?61MONASH.prod.primo.1701-sg=BLFICAAK; PRIMO_RT=` (sanitized). you'd have to supply a valide `JESSIONID` at least. Read the docs of your java classes by what mechanism they support cookies.

Answer (score 0):

replace `&amp;` with `&` in last code (String url="..)